# Safety Considerations for Wired Bathroom Cleaning Electric Brush

Tags: safety, underwater

I've this [Hurricane Spin Scrubber](https://bulbheadinternational.com/products/hurricane-spin-scrubber-1) basically a battery operated surface cleaning brush. I love its convenience and effectiveness however I'm getting sick of the battery power limitation though, minutes of runtime and towards the end in limited runtime life with battery voltage dropping, brush's spinning actions slows, so really actual cleaning worthy power life is like 50-75% of the rated life. Battery also isn't easily accessible to keep hot swapping until job is done.

Multimeter measured 3-4 V DC and 4-5 A power being consumed by the motor coming from freshly charged unit's built-in battery. Motor isn't accessible to get its model # or read any labeled power specs hence the tapped power reading via multimeter.

I'm considering using low voltage power supply like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R4NK3D1) to hardwire power supply to the motor. Plug in the power supply brick outside bathroom away from any splattering water, use long tens of feet cable running from that power supply to the electric cleaning brush with adequate waterproof seal so water doesn't enter brush unit where power cable enters.

Is this too dangerous especially given wet environment of its application? I was considering adding in a [6A circuit breaker](https://ace4parts.com/circuit-protection/6-amp-50vdc-250vac-circuit-breaker.html) downstream of the power supply, haven't found any decent [overvoltage protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536802/overvoltage-undervoltage-overcurrent-1-12v-dc-5a-off-the-shelf-product-recommend) yet. Worst case imaginations, over the time insulation of cable running from power supply to brush unit wares and my wet hands/body touch 5V DC 5A, is that unsafe, not worth pursuing? Any other improvement recommendations to safety or otherwise to solutions?

Comment: In general this seems like a good way to win a Darwin Award.  But if you were going to plug this in, you should be using a GFI outlet.  GFI outlets will disconnect whenever a short to something else (like your body) is detected.  Coincidentally, GFI outlets are normally found in a bathroom.  So your plan to plug in the device to an outlet in another room is probably less safe.  Also a 6A breaker is way too big.  You can be killed by as little as 0.1A.

Comment: I agree this seems sketchy hence asking for feedback from relevantly educated :)
Intention for using 6A breaker was to trip in case something causes more than expected 5A being drawn. If I used smaller inline overcurrent protection like a few mA fuse, it'd trip the circuit before motor brush gets any use. I agree with your and many's recommendation here though that counting on GFCI is more relevant here than breaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safety, the important information is on the back of the product and impossible tor read. I can see the box in a box symbol the means that it is double insulated. There should also be something to indicate it conforms to applicable safety standards. As mentioned in another answer, Residual Current Disconnect AKA Ground Fault Interrupt protection is important. You should not need to add overcurrent or overvoltage protection

You have not asked about compatibility with the motor. That is likely to be a problem. A motor requiring 4-5 amps to run requires much more than that to start, perhaps as much as 50 amps. The initial current will likely last only a fraction of a second, but that will likely be enough to make the power supply shut off for overcurrent protection. You would be better off with a simple unregulated 5-volt power supply that has a high tolerance for the very brief but high pulse of current that the motor is likely to draw when it starts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the box in a box symbol on linked power supply indicating output being double insulated from input. I will google around to learn how to verify the isolation.

Comment: To the point of needing higher current to start the motor, e.g. 50 A to start vs 5 A operational, hmm how do I handle this? Is it safe to use unregulard power supply (albeit low 5V 5A / 25W) one in wet environment that could potentially let through (unregulard) high voltage momentarily albeit at lower current?

Comment: An unregulated supply will not let through high voltage when the load current is high. The high current will tend to cause the supply voltage to drop.

Answer (score 0):

GFCI receptacle will protect you. And better make sure the output isolated from input, because your device not suited for high voltage. I see another problem. Battery powered device not working well with any kind of power supply. Motor when starts take bigger current. Battery provides start current but power supply may not. Your device may not start. PS should have output current restriction, not switching off in case of overload. And supply enough current for starting motor.

Comment: Would power supply plugged into GFCI outlet work adequately or should I add standalone RCD breaker downstream of power supply?

Comment: PS plugged into GFCI receptacle is enough.